# cap deploy:web:disabled does not exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano

Here are the taks from cap -T

```
cap bundle:install                    # Install the current Bundler environment.
cap delayed_job:restart               # Restart the delayed_job process
cap delayed_job:start                 # Start the delayed_job process
cap delayed_job:stop                  # Stop the delayed_job process
cap deploy                            # Deploys your project.
cap deploy:assets:clean               # Run the asset clean rake task.
cap deploy:assets:precompile          # Run the asset precompilation rake task.
cap deploy:check                      # Test deployment dependencies.
cap deploy:cleanup                    # Clean up old releases.
cap deploy:cold                       # Deploys and starts a `cold' application.
cap deploy:create_symlink             # Updates the symlink to the most recen...
cap deploy:migrate                    # Run the migrate rake task.
cap deploy:migrations                 # Deploy and run pending migrations.
cap deploy:pending                    # Displays the commits since your last ...
cap deploy:pending:diff               # Displays the `diff' since your last d...
cap deploy:restart                    # Blank task exists as a hook into whic...
cap deploy:rollback                   # Rolls back to a previous version and ...
cap deploy:rollback:code              # Rolls back to the previously deployed...
cap deploy:setup                      # Prepares one or more servers for depl...
cap deploy:start                      # Blank task exists as a hook into whic...
cap deploy:stop                       # Blank task exists as a hook into whic...
cap deploy:symlink                    # Deprecated API.
cap deploy:update                     # Copies your project and updates the s...
cap deploy:update_code                # Copies your project to the remote ser...
cap deploy:upload                     # Copy files to the currently deployed ...
cap imagemagick:install               # Install the latest release of Imagema...
cap invoke                            # Invoke a single command on the remote...
cap libcurl:install                   # Install the latest release of libcurl
cap libxml:install                    # Install the latest release of libxml
cap multistage:prepare                # Stub out the staging config files.
cap nginx:install                     # Install latest stable release of nginx
cap nginx:restart                     # restart nginx
cap nginx:setup                       # Setup nginx configuration for this ap...
cap nginx:start                       # start nginx
cap nginx:stop                        # stop nginx
cap nodejs:install                    # Install the latest relase of Node.js
cap postgresql_client:create_database # Create a database for this application.
cap postgresql_client:dump            # Dump database
cap postgresql_client:duplicate       # Duplicate database
cap postgresql_client:get             # Get database
cap postgresql_client:import          # Import database
cap postgresql_client:install         # Install dev libraries PostgreSQL.
cap postgresql_client:restore         # Restore from ftp
cap postgresql_client:setup           # Generate the database.yml configurati...
cap postgresql_client:symlink         # Symlink the database.yml file into la...
cap postgresql_server:install         # Install the latest stable release of ...
cap production                        # Set the target stage to `production'.
cap rbenv:install                     # Install rbenv, Ruby, and the Bundler gem
cap rbenv:install_ruby                # Install ruby
cap rbenv:upgrade                     # Upgrade rbenv
cap shell                             # Begin an interactive Capistrano session.
cap staging                           # Set the target stage to `staging'.
cap unicorn:restart                   # restart unicorn
cap unicorn:setup                     # Setup Unicorn initializer and app con...
cap unicorn:start                     # start unicorn
cap unicorn:stop
```

As you can see there is no cap deploy:web:disabled task. Where is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That functionality was recently extracted to a [separate gem](https://github.com/tvdeyen/capistrano-maintenance):

Install the gem via rubygems:

```
gem install capistrano-maintenance
```

And put this line into your deploy.rb file:

```
require 'capistrano/maintenance'
```